# offset not changing after jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

http://plnkr.co/edit/c6OaitTTvLhltk7b3muf?p=preview

I'm working on a jQuery animation and need to have the animated divs retain their new offset after the animation ends.

The goal of the animation is to be able to click on one of the smaller circles at the bottom and it will swap places/size with the larger circle at the top.

```
function leadershipToShow(id) {
  console.log('leadershipToShow (' + id + ')');
  var x = $('.activeLeadership').offset().left;
  var y = $('.activeLeadership').offset().top;
  var h = $('.activeLeadership').height();
  var w = $('.activeLeadership').width();
  if($(id).hasClass('activeLeadership')){ console.log('already selected');return false; }
  console.log('x ' + x + ', y ' + y);
  console.log($(id).offset());
  var xi = $(id).offset().left;
  var yi = $(id).offset().top;
  console.log('xi ' + xi + ', yi ' + yi);
  var hi = $(id).height();
  var wi = $(id).width();
  var xOffset = Math.abs(x - xi);
  var yOffset = Math.abs(y - yi);

  console.log('xOffset ' + xOffset + ', yOffset ' + yOffset);

  $(id).animate({
  left: -xOffset + 15,
  top: -yOffset, 
  height: h,
  width: w
  }, 500, 'linear', function() {console.log('Id Animation Complete');});

  var selected = $('.activeLeadership'); 
  console.log(selected.offset());
  selected.animate({
  left: xOffset + 15,
  top: yOffset, 
  height: hi,
  width: wi
  }, 500, 'linear',function() {
    console.log('selected Animation Complete');
    console.log('new active ' + $('.activeLeadership').attr('id'));
    console.log('new active position x ' +   $('.activeLeadership').offset().left      + ', y ' +   $('.activeLeadership').offset().top);
    console.log('previous active ' + selected.attr('id'));
    console.log('previous active position x ' + selected.offset().left + ', y   '          + selected.offset().top);}
   );
  $(id).addClass('activeLeadership');
  selected.removeClass('activeLeadership');

}
```

Comment: What behavior are you getting with the current code? Is there anything errors or warning in your error log. Could you add comments in your code?

Comment: I think the problem is that when you click the second time on the small circles, they will double their offset position or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help with this and figured it out. The solution is that you have to take the offsets of the divs based on their first offset locations. After they've been animated, moving them again is always relative to their starting offset. So to make this work you have to store their starting offset locations in a global variable outside of the function. With an if statement you then associate the id of the div with the variable of the initial offset. Then it is just a matter of taking the difference between the div you want to animate's initial offset and the location you want to move it to.

updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/c6OaitTTvLhltk7b3muf?p=preview

```
var circle0 = { 'left': $('#circle0').offset().left, 'top': $('#circle0').offset().top };
var bigCircle = { 'height': $('.activeLeadership').height(), 'width': $('.activeLeadership').width() };
var circle1 = { 'left': $('#circle1').offset().left, 'top': $('#circle1').offset().top };
var circle2 = { 'left': $('#circle2').offset().left, 'top':              $('#circle2').offset().top };
var circle3 = { 'left': $('#circle3').offset().left, 'top':       $('#circle3').offset().top };
var circle4 = { 'left': $('#circle4').offset().left, 'top':   $('#circle4').offset().top };
var otherCircles = { 'height': $('#circle1').height(), 'width':   $('#circle1').width() };
var time = 400;

function leadershipToShow(id) {
  var circleToMoveUp = $(id);
  if(circleToMoveUp.hasClass('activeLeadership')){ return false; }
  var originOfCircleToMoveUp;
  if(id === '#circle0'){ originOfCircleToMoveUp = circle0; }
  else if(id === '#circle1'){ originOfCircleToMoveUp = circle1; }
  else if(id === '#circle2'){ originOfCircleToMoveUp = circle2; }
  else if(id === '#circle3'){ originOfCircleToMoveUp = circle3; }
  else if(id === '#circle4'){ originOfCircleToMoveUp = circle4; }
  var xOffsetUp = circle0.left - originOfCircleToMoveUp.left;
  var yOffsetUp = circle0.top - originOfCircleToMoveUp.top;

  var circleToMoveDown = $('.activeLeadership');
  var originOfCircleToMoveDown;
  if(circleToMoveDown.attr('id') === 'circle0'){ originOfCircleToMoveDown = circle0; }
  else if(circleToMoveDown.attr('id') === 'circle1'){ originOfCircleToMoveDown = circle1; }
  else if(circleToMoveDown.attr('id') === 'circle2'){ originOfCircleToMoveDown = circle2; }
  else if(circleToMoveDown.attr('id') === 'circle3'){ originOfCircleToMoveDown = circle3; }
  else if(circleToMoveDown.attr('id') === 'circle4'){     originOfCircleToMoveDown = circle4; }
  var xOffsetDown = circleToMoveUp.offset().left -  originOfCircleToMoveDown.left;
  var yOffsetDown = circleToMoveUp.offset().top -   originOfCircleToMoveDown.top;

  /* SMALL CIRCLE to BIG CIRCLE animation */
  circleToMoveUp.animate({
    left: xOffsetUp + 15,
    top: yOffsetUp, 
    height: bigCircle.height,
    width: bigCircle.width
  }, time, 'linear');
  /* BIG CIRCLE to SMALL CIRCLE animation */
  circleToMoveDown.animate({
    left: xOffsetDown + 15,
    top: yOffsetDown, 
    height: otherCircles.height,
    width: otherCircles.width
  }, time, 'linear');

  circleToMoveUp.addClass('activeLeadership');
  circleToMoveDown.removeClass('activeLeadership');
}
```